# as3 air can not connect remote server

Tags: actionscript-3, server, air, fiddler, ashx

I developed a desktop app with Adobe air.

In order to run it sends a code to my server (vps) the server checks the code and respond with true or false. if true the app goes on if not the app quit.

I installed it already on a lot of pcs. and it works fine.

On one pc it is not working. The app tells me that there is error 2032
I tried to use [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). it doesn't show anything when I run the app!in other pcs fiddler does show my app traffic in and out.

- I tried to temporarily disable the antivirus (eset)
- I tried to temporarily disable the firewall (windows)
- I looked at the list of installed apps, it doesn't seem that there is one that might block it.

The app post the code to a [ashx](https://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx)
a ping to the server ip is ok (and I ping also to the site name)
This pc OS is win 7 pro.
What else can cause such a thing??

The code that I use to send data to the server (AS3)

```
public function sendAndGet(objToServer:Object,callback:Function)
{
mCallback = callback;
mURLLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
mURLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, gotDataFromServer);
mURLLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ServerConErr);
mURLLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS,serverStatus);
var str:String = obj2str(objToServer);
mURLVars = new URLVariables("str="+str);
mURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
mURLRequest.data = mURLVars;
mURLLoader.load(mURLRequest);
}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code, and exact error message that comes from the flash debug player (there are a good many things that can cause a 2032, and the error details can elaborate).   Without these things, people can only wildly speculate as to the nature of your problem.

Comment: Thaks - I added the relevant code. I think it is not a code question. It works great in all pcs, my question is what else (but firewall and anti visrus) can block server connection. I want speculation, I will check them one by one.

Comment: What about the error details?  That's probably the most important piece of information you could provide.

Comment: That is the problem. that "error 2032" is all I get. and I think it is because the request doesn't get out. Fiddler which is supposed to catch every request doesn't see it.

Comment: Are you publishing your app using captive runtime?  If not, is the problem PC running a different version of AIR?  Also, double-check `Security.sandboxType`: I'd expect `Security.APPLICATION`, but a discrepancy there would explain this behavior. https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3f.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the problem, I installed wireshark.
When I tried to run it I got a message:
The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing
I looked for a solution to this problem and I found it in this [link](https://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/the-program-cant-start-because-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0dll-is-missing-f2702.html)
after I updated Windows, I tried to run my app and it worked perfectly.